# StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of is stale

Tags: python, selenium

I'm scraping links using selenium. I can print my links with my loop but I can't navigate to them because and get all of the information
I get the following error:
Message: The element reference is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    author=[]
    MAX_PAGE_NUM = 2
    url=r"C:\\Users\\PERSONL\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"

    driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=url)
    with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write("Name")

    for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
        url = url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/results/" + "#/page/" + str(i) 
        driver.get(url)
        names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="name table-participant"]')
        num_page_items = len(names)
        with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
            for i in range(num_page_items):
                author.append(names[i].text)
                f.write(names[i].text)

    driver.close()
```

and also for this code can you please add wedriverwait also for this code :

```
    ff=['https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/tottenham-manchester-city-ddkDE7Ld/#over-under;2','https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/burnley-bournemouth-xSUUEVHO/#over-under;2']
    webD=wb.Chrome(r'C:\Users\PERSONL\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe')
    k=len(ff)
    for i in range(k):
        webD.get(ff[i])
        c03= webD.find_elements_by_class_name('bt-2')
        c05=c03.find_elements_by_class_name('table-container')
        c04=c03.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')
        kk.append(c04)

        
    fla=kk[0]

    print(fla)
    for i in fla:
        m=i.text
        num.append(m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a few tweaks to your script.

The key to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException` was to allow the table to load before collecting `names`. Use `WebDriverWait` on visibility of element for that.

You can also iterate through `names` directly, without the need for index (see `for name in names:` line). I have also added a `.rstrip()` which removes any trailing whitespace in the collected text. You can remove it and see how your `.csv` will look like to understand the need.

```
author=[]
MAX_PAGE_NUM = 2

with open('resultss.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Name\n")

for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league-2017-2018/results/" + "#/page/" + str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table#tournamentTable')))
    names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td[@class="name table-participant"]')
    print(len(names))
    print(names[0].text)
    with open('resultss.csv', 'a') as f:
        for name in names:
            author.append(name.text.rstrip())
            f.write(name.text.rstrip()+"\n")

driver.close()
```

These imports are required for `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```